# Negate a pair of characters in RegEx Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, p5.js

Currently have `/([^\s\+\(]+)\^([^\s\,\+\)]+)/g` to convert `x^y` into `pow(x,y)`.

Works for:

```
y = x 
y = x^2 
y = x^2 + y^2
y = 5*(x^2 + y^2)
y = (x^2 + y^2)
y = pow(x^2+y^2, 2)
```

However I want to be able to do something like this:

```
y = abs(x)^2 --> y = pow(abs(x), 2)
```

I currently have `\(` in the first negated capture group to stop `5*(x^2)` being messed up, however what I really want to do is negate `*(` as a pair, so the bracket is only negated when preceded by parantheses.

Is there a way to negate specific occurences of consequtive characters?

Comment: Why are you doing this? Make the formulas look nicer or for prepare it for the actual calculation? If the latter is the case, take a look at [math.js](http://mathjs.org/).

Comment: @wp78de it is for actual calculation, but I'm running it in an environment where I don't have access to external libraries (OpenProcessing). I am also trying to further my understanding of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could avoid advanced regex features altogether and add a simple alternation for the function parameter:

```
(\w+\([^\s+()]+\)|[^\s+()]+)\^(\w+\([^\s+()]+\)|[^\s,+()]+)
```

Actually, this should not only be added to the first parameter since the second parameter could be a function as well.

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/qxTNru/2)

The basic idea here is to capture functions and regular parameters separately.

- `(` capture group 1
- `(\w+\([^\s+()]+\)` captures a function like `abs(-4)`:

  - `\w+` looking for one or more alphanum letters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)
  - ( followed be an literal opening parenthesis
  - `[^\s+()]+` then, the content: everything that is not white-space or `()`
  - `\)` and a closing parenthesis.
- `|` alternation
- `[^\s+()]+` regular parameter
- `)` closing $1

then the `\^` followed by the second capture group that applies the same approach.

Comment: This is perfect, could you add an explanation?

Comment: I changed it slightly into `(\w*\([^\s()]+\)|[^\s+()]+)\^(\w*\([^\s()]+\)|[^\s,+()]+)` to allow the case `y = (x+5)^(z+5)`, but otherwise exactly what I needed.

Comment: @FreddieR Awesome. I've added the explanation.